# Unwanted 'jumping' error on hover

Tags: html, css

I am writing a simple navigation with 6 boxes sitting side by side in 2 columns. On hover the boxes display a yellow border. For some reason when I hover over the first box, the other boxes 'jump'. This only occurs in IE.
Here is my code:

```css
img.thumbImage {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100px;
  height: auto;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

a .listing {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 48%;
  float: left;
  padding-right: 80px;
  color: #000;
  border: transparent solid 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-size: 30px;
  margin-right: 2%;
  height: 150px;
  display: block;
}

a:hover .listing {
  border: 10px solid #ffe800 !important;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  height: 150px;
  display: block;
}

a:hover .listing h3 {
  color: #ffe800 !important;
}

.listing h3 {
  margin-top: -24px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <div class="listing">
    <img src="#" class="thumbImage" />
    <h3>TITLE</h3>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed et leo ut nulla viverra hendrerit sit amet.
  </div>
</a>
<a href="#">
  <div class="listing">
    <img src="#" class="thumbImage" />
    <h3>TITLE</h3>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed et leo ut nulla viverra hendrerit sit amet.
  </div>
</a>
<a href="#">
  <div class="listing">
    <img src="#" class="thumbImage" />
    <h3>TITLE</h3>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed et leo ut nulla viverra hendrerit sit amet.
  </div>
</a>
<a href="#">
  <div class="listing">
    <img src="#" class="thumbImage" />
    <h3>TITLE</h3>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed et leo ut nulla viverra hendrerit sit amet.
  </div>
</a>
<a href="#">
  <div class="listing">
    <img src="#" class="thumbImage" />
    <h3>TITLE</h3>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed et leo ut nulla viverra hendrerit sit amet.
  </div>
</a>
<a href="#">
  <div class="listing">
    <img src="#" class="thumbImage" />
    <h3>TITLE</h3>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed et leo ut nulla viverra hendrerit sit amet.
  </div>
</a>
```

Unfortunately I'm restricted with WordPress so responses without script would be appreciated.
Before hover screenshot

[image]

After hover screenshot
[image]

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of how the output appears to "jump" on IE?

Comment: Thanks for your review. I have just updated the post to show you a before and after screenshot. Much appreciated.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean, that is because you're adding border to your container on hover and that much space occupied makes the neighbouring containers shift from their position, presuming they have a certain margin to each other.

Comment: You'll see though that I've compensated for this border and that's why the first box is the same width as the box underneath. I did this by adding a 10px transparent border initially and then 10px yellow border on hover. The jump doesn't occur for any other boxes when hovered either - just the first. In addition, this only occurs in IE. Very frustrating! Stupid IE!

Comment: Investigate the nested elements to ensure none of them change any spacing property values on `:hover`, like `margins` on the nested `h3` elements. You'll probably need to be thorough in this investigation so that you don't miss anything. To start troubleshooting this, I would recommend declaring `overflow: none` on the anchor tags (`a`) to rule out the possibility of any nested elements affecting the containing element's placement.

Comment: Great suggestion - thanks! I'll post when I (hopefully) have the solution. Again, thank you

Comment: I found the solution. As I was using a WordPress template, there was a margin in the template applied to h3 tags. I overrode the margin to 0 with my own stylesheet and this fixed the issue. Thanks again for helping me out. Your advice really made me analyse the code.

Comment: Nicely done, good to know and glad you came right.